# A kind of exponential concavity for polynomials?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, inequalities, convex-analysis

Is there $C > 0$ such that the inequality
$$
\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} p(n)^{a_n} \leq p\left(C\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} n^{a_n}\right)
$$
holds for all finitely supported sequences $(a_n)$ with $a_n\geq 0$ and $\sum_n a_n = 1$ and polynomials with nonnegative coefficients $p\in \mathbb{R}_+[X]$?

Is it even possible to take $C=1$?

It's clear that the inequality trivially holds with $C = 1$ whenever $p$ is a monomial.

Comment: Is there a typo? Usually, a function $p$ is _log-concave_ if $\operatorname{log}\circ p$ is concave (meaning that there should only be one logarithm on the right hand side).

Comment: @PhilippLampe: you're right, that was a braino. I will edit my question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example by Philipp Lampe can be modified to prove that no such $C$ exists:

Suppose $k$ is an arbitrary positive integer and take $p(x)=x(x+k^2-1)$. Now choose $a_1=a_n=\frac{1}{2}$ for some $n\geq 1$ and we get that $C$ must satisfy
$$\sqrt{p(1)p(n)}\le p(C\sqrt{n})$$
$$\iff \sqrt{k^2n(n+k^2-1)}\le C\sqrt{n}(C\sqrt{n}+k^2-1)$$
but we notice that as we let $n\to \infty$ the left side is $\sim kn$ and the right side is $\sim C^2 n$ which gives $C\geq \sqrt{k}$. Since $k$ was arbitrary we conclude that no such constant exists.

Answer (score 4):

**It is not possible to take $C=1$.**

We consider the polynomial $p=x^2+x$ and the sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_1=a_2=1/2$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise. Then

\begin{align*}
\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} p(n)^{a_n}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6}=2\sqrt{3};
&&p\left(\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n^{a_n}\right)=p\left(\sqrt{2}\right)=2+\sqrt{2}.
\end{align*}
However, $2\sqrt{3}>2+\sqrt{2}$.